# Мобильный клиент, серверное приложение и платформа

Tags: клиент-сервер, мобильные-приложения

Есть некоторая система с двухуровневой архитектурой (клиент - БД), для которой нужно мобильное приложение.

Есть большой запас времени, но не знаю с чего начать. И если с клиентской стороной мне всё понятно. Но с серверной частью - не совсем.

Часто встречаю, что одним из вариантов платформы является ASP.NET Core. Но я не очень понимаю зачем нужны какие-то платформы. Почему я не могу, например, написать серверное приложение, скажем на C++ с сокетами, которое будет обрабатывать приходящие от клиента запросы, вытаскивать нужные данные из БД и отправлять клиенту?

На просторах сети я не нашёл какого-то внятного ответа, и наличие/использование какой-либо платформы принимается как данность. Прошу разъясните что к чему мне.

Comment: Что хотите, то и используйте. Всё зависит от ваших знаний.

Comment: Только не используйте ASP.NET   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: вообще для таких целей насколько я знаю (могу ошибаться) создаются апи которое помогает приложению взаимодействовать с бд, например rest api есть